# C++ Dialog box With timer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, messagebox, dialog

I couldn't find a simple tutorial on how to make a dialog box with decrementing timer. I don't need the timer to be accurate or actually reflect my program's inner timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended using SetTimer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx
Thanks!

Comment: +1 for coming back and updating the question with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This [countdown timer tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/progressindicators/article.php/c4961/) doesn't help? Source code is included, and you probably can fit the code to "decrement" the timer, or show time info instead.